# Pass service/provider for specific child component to use as inject value

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-injector

FormService contains state for parts of form.

```js
export class ArrayComponent implements OnInit {

   formServices: FormService[] = [];

   constructor(
        @Inject(FormService) public parentFormService: FormService,
    ) {
    }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      // Here I create lets say 10 FormService objects, that have to go to there separated child components.
      this.parentFormService.data$.subscribe((d: any[]) => d.foreach((v: any) => this.formServices.push(new FormService(v))))
   }
}
```

Lets imagine that based on some data, I create new FormService. I need to be able to pass this created FormService for a specific child component.

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of formServices">
   <array-item [inject/providers]="s"></array-item>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a way to pass this injectable service into a component as a Injectable?

You may be asking why would I need it to be injectable or why cant I just pass it in as @Input. The issue is that down in the tree of components there is for example a `TextInputComponent` that is trying to Inject a FormService to store state and do other Input things.

I pretty much want to do what `@Component({providers: []})` does, but outside of the component, so I can directly control the provided Service and have access to it from Parent and Child component.

EDIT:
// More precise thing i want to do simplified

```
<array-item [inject/providers]="formServices[0]"></array-item>
<array-item [inject/providers]="formServices[1]"></array-item>
<array-item [inject/providers]="formServices[2]"></array-item>
<array-item [inject/providers]="formServices[3]"></array-item>
```

and then down the line inside of array-item component there is a component that uses @Inject to inject FormService and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible.

For every child its possible to create an `Injector` like this -

```
...

constructor(
        ...
        private injector: Injector,
        ...
    ) {
    }
...

Injector.create({providers: [...providder here...], parent: this.injector})
```

And then pass it to a component that renders further children like this -

```
...
@Input() injector!: Injector;
...
    constructor(
        ...
        public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        ...
    ) {

    }
...
ngOnInit(): void {
        ...
        const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(...Component..., {
            ...
            injector: this.injector
            ...
            }),
        });
        ... // Set @Input attributes here with component.instance.
        component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually all children can access parent providers, so simple:

```
@Component({providers: [FormService]})
```

in parent component does all you want.

**For difference service instances, you can design it like this:**

Add input for component `array-item [service-config]="..."`.
In component:

```
@Inject(FormService) public parentFormService: FormService
ngOnInit() {
     this.parentFormService.reConfigure(this.serviceConfig);
}
```

and in component children you can access this service.

Comment: Remember that I have to make infinite amounts of separated instances of FormService. This only allows me to make one.

Comment: Looking at your edit, how would that allow parent component still to have access to the services and at the same time have 10 different instances of the service? Each service for a different child component has different states. {a: 0} for first component, {a: 1} for second and so on.